# Closing a workbook without stopping vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep running into an issue where the worksheet in question gets updated, and then doesn't reflect the changes until I close and re-open the book. It's not really a big deal, I just want to simplify it a bit into a single button click.

I was told that this is impossible to do because closing a workbook will immediately stop execution of code, so you can't reopen the book. But since, I have learned about the PERSONAL.xlsb, and figured since it's a persistent workbook, it could handle the code execution to save, close, and reopen the workbook.

Basically, here's what I've got in the main worksheet:

```
Public Sub Refresh()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.xlsb!Module1.RefreshCurrentSheet",ThisWorkbook.Name,_
                     ThisWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

Which then calls the personal.xlsb macro "Refreshcurrentsheet":

```
Private Sub RefreshCurrentSheet(ByVal sheetname, Optional ByVal sheetfullname = 0)
    Workbooks(sheetname).Close
    MsgBox "So far so good!" 'I never see this box
    Workbooks(sheetfullname).Open
    MsgBox "No errors here..." 'I never see this box
End Sub
```

This successfully closes the workbook in question, but code execution stops and it doesn't reopen. Is there a way around this? Some way to run the second macro in the persistent sheet without code execution stopping?

Comment: Is the `Refresh` sub in a different workbook then the `Personal.xlsb`?

Comment: Yes, it is on a separate book. I feel like this is where the problem is, because all of the code is called from this book, even though the rest is written in PERSONAL.XLSB

Comment: Once you reopen the book from another book (macro) you have to restart whatever code you want run in the newly opened book.

Comment: your problem is with the `Workbooks(sheetfullname).Open` statement. It's incorrect syntax. Change it to `Workbooks.Open sheetfullname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reopen the workbook using this code inside it (there is no need to use other workbook):

```
Sub test()
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This just worked perfectly! I don't understand how...But it worked exactly as needed. @Fadi Where have you been all of my life?? And why haven't you shared this on any of the other posts about this? I'm going to share this answer and credit you :)

Comment: @Fadi - maybe I misunderstood. removed DV

Comment: @C-Love511, you can share it as you want , I'm very happy to this.